# How to sort a vector<any>?

Tags: c++, sorting, any

Is it possible to sort vector<any> by using std::sort or somehow else?

I was trying to do smth like this

> 

```
  vector<any> va{ 55ll, 'a', -1};
   
    sort(va.begin(), va.end(), [](const any& lhs, const any& rhs) { return any_cast<decltype(lhs.type())>(lhs) > any_cast<decltype(lhs.type()>(rhs) });
```

Comment: how do you want it to be sorted?

Comment: What does it means to compare `"foo"` with `42`?  Which should be considered less?

Comment: What does "I was trying to do smth like this" mean?  If you tried it, what happened?  If you didn't, why are you posting it?

Comment: @NathanOliver String representations of objects of different types can be sorted lexicographically (also known as _somehow_ sort order).

Comment: The fundamental problem with your approach is that `lhs.type()` is a runtime function, and `decltype` is a compile-time function. C++ does not work this way, on a fundamental level.

Comment: Your use of `any_cast` indicates you expect, at some point, to be able to cast the `any` back to whatever type is stored automatically. It is not possible to do this with `std::any`, you eventually need to explicitly provide the type the `any` stores to the cast. This type cannot be deduced from the `std::any`. A stand alone `std::any` is basically always useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to sort vector by using std::sort or somehow else?

It is possible. You can do it the same way as sorting *any*thing else: By defining a function to compare two `std::any` with strict total order.

> ```
> any_cast<decltype(lhs.type())>(lhs)
> ```

This won't work. `std::any::type` returns `std::type_info`, and unless you store an object of type `std::type_info` in `std::any`, the `std::any_cast` will fail.

---

There are many ways to order objects of heterogeneous types.

A relatively simple way is to primarily order by the type of the object. A caveat here is that the order of types is not portable across systems:

```
bool
any_less_type(const std::any& l, const std::any& r)
{
    auto& lt = l.type();
    auto& rt = r.type();
    return std::type_index(lt) < std::type_index(rt);
}
```

Then, objects of same type that are orderable may be further ordered, but that feature may have to be limited to a small set of types as if you were using `std::variant`.